# Cannot manage to clip DEM raster using vector for calculating flood depth on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, flood

I have a huge DEM that I want to clip on QGIS based on a flood vector layer so that I can easily calculate the flood depth based on the highest DEM value in the flooded area. I am trying to use the "clip by mask" function, putting null values as 0 and checking the "maintain mask extent" box, but my raster just won't clip. It stays as a squared polygon and nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both the raster and the vector layer must be projected to the same coordinate reference system for the clip to work correctly. Are they?

Comment: Yes. Still not working...basically nothing changes after the clipping.

Comment: Raster files are always rectangular with fixed number of rows and columns. Did you expect that clip would work like a cookie cutter? However, if you set the nodata value then the area between the crop polygon and the borders of the rectangle should be filled with this value. Doesn't that happen?

Comment: I tried but I am not sure which value should I set as Nodata. I put both 0 and -99.99999 but changes nothing.

Comment: Some screen shots might be helpful.